# Using MsalService's loginRedirect(): void method in an ngrx effect to determine login success?

Tags: angular, ngrx, azure-ad-msal, ngrx-effects

I'm using Azure AD to log into my angular app. Using MSAL, I am able to do this with `loginPopup()` method of the MsalService. Also I'm using ngrx to manage my state. The relevant code excerpts look like this

Login button on /login page calls

```
login(): void {
    this._store.dispatch(new Login());
}
```

Which triggers this action

```
export class Login implements Action {
    readonly type = AuthActionTypes.LOGIN;
}
```

Which itself gets captured by an effect, that on successful receipt of an id_token checks the validity of its signature (which then, when successful, dispatches the LoginSuccess action). Else the login is deemed failed, by dispatching the LoginFail action.

```
@Effect()
doLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN),
    switchMap(() => {
        return observableFrom(this._msal.loginPopup()).pipe(
            map(idToken => new CheckTokenValidity(idToken)),
            catchError(error => of(new LoginFail(error)))
        );
    })
);
```

This works fine, however instead of the `MsalService.loginPopup(): Promise<any>` I now want to use `MsalService.loginRedirect(): void`. But as a problem, I expect my ngrx effects chain to break, because then there is no promise anymore but only void returned.

How would I go about *fixing* this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I'll give it an answer since it still pops up when searching for NGRX and Msal/Adal.

Update your Effect to not dispatch an action it'll break the chain.

```
@Effect({dispatch: false)
doLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN),
    tap(() => {
        // void function
    })
);
```